# Parallel Processing in Python with nested loop

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Due to performance issue, i would like to run in parallel my function in python :

```
import multiprocessing as mp

source_nodes = [10413173,    10414530,   10414530,   10437199]
sink_nodes =  [10420346,     10438770,   10438711,   10414530,   10436258]
path =[]    


def createpath(source,sink):
    for i in source:
        for j in sink:
            path = path + list(nx.all_simple_paths(Directed_G,i,j))
    return path
```

From my understanding i must give 1 iterable to apply function. but my idea was to do something like :

```
results = [pool.apply(createpath, args=(source_nodes, sink_nodes))]
```

And then don't give any iterable object to applyfunction
I managed to get it work, but i don't think it run on parallel.

Do you think i should include the apply function inside the first loop ?

Comment: If you want to run your loop in parallel, you could try to use tool similar to openMP in C++, e.g., [Pymp](https://github.com/classner/pymp). This allows you to give each core its portion of iterations and all core the loop in prallel. You should use reduction to get you result.

Comment: Oh, thanks but I would like to avoid installing any others external tool, knowing that I’m running this code on a virtual machine managed by an other department.

Comment: So then, maybe you could try to achieve something similar, by giving range of loop in argument. Then each core would process only its own part of the whole loop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, can you develop a little bit more your thought, I reckon it’s a bit hard to understand for me

Answer (score 2):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


source_nodes = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
sink_nodes =  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]


def sum_values(parameter_tuple):
    source,sink, start, stop = parameter_tuple
    out = 0
    for i in range(start, stop):
        val_i = source[i]
        for j in sink:
            out += val_i*j
    return out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    params = (source_nodes, sink_nodes, 0, 6)
    print(sum_values(params))
    with Pool(2) as p:
        print(p.map(sum_values, [
            (source_nodes, sink_nodes, 0, 3),
            (source_nodes, sink_nodes, 3, 6),
        ]))
```

You can try to run this one. This runs parallel with map pattern on pool of 2 threads. In this case your output result is the sum of result of each process from pool.

Comment: This code does not assemble the requested **list-of-lists**, generated for all source-sink paths ( neither a pair of partial lists, each one per a Pool-member process, to be later joined ), as the O/P has requested. Also the scaling matters, try to validate your code's scaling somewhere above 1E9 by 1E9 source-sink graphs to see the costs of doing the job in separated processes and post the corrected code and its scaling properties benchmarked